# Conditional Probability and simultaneity of events

Tags: probability, statistics

We have two events $A$ and $B$, and i'm trying to understand why :

$P(B|A)P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$

What i think is that if we are searching the probability that two events A and B happen simultaneously, maybe the fact that A arrives before B causes a different probability respect the case in which B arrives before A.
Why am i wrong ?

Comment: In the probabilistic model the issue "simultaneous" is not captured.

Comment: This is best understood with cards imo. Consider picking two cards both spades out of 52 card deck. Intuitively we quickly say the probability of fhat happening is $13/52 \cdot 12/51$. Note that latter fraction depended on the fact that one spade was already chosen (and not replaced). This is precisely $P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B|A)$ where $A$ is the event that a spade card was picked and $B$ is the event that another spade was picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@drhab pretty much explained it - you want both events to happen, this doesn't really mean that they happen simultaneously, there is no such thing as "time" when it comes to events - you can think of them as outcomes.

If you want informal explanation of the formula:

The probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening is the same as the probability of $A$ happening times the probability of $B$ happening given that $A$ happened. If you swap $A$ and $B$ you get the other identity.